# Where does enclosing function reside post its execution or after returning closure function?

Tags: javascript, closures

Having understood the basics of Closures there is one doubt that's still haunting me :

**Where does enclosing function reside post its execution or after returning closure function ?**

I believe functions reside in stack data structure and knocked off the top of stack once function finishes its execution / returns any value.

But in Closures, inner function will still have to access to the state of Enclosing function, how ?

```
function sayHello(name) {
  var text = name + ' !!!'; // Local variable
  return function(wish) { console.log(wish + ', ' +text); }
}

var say = sayHello('Bob');

say('Hey');
say('Hello');
```

Where is `sayHello` present once it returns a function, as its removed from function stack frame ?

Comment: *"But in Closures, inner function will still have to access to the state of Enclosing function, how ?"* That's an implementation detail and different engines might do this differently, but the environment (which holds the bindings) is likely stored on the heap.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for ur answer. I have few more questions like : where do Functions and Objects reside in Javascript ? Dint find any help in online. Do u have any resources which throws more light on Memory allocation and management in JS ?

Answer (score 1):

This is one very good article on this.

https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/js_closures

Scope chain

When any JavaScript code is executing, it needs some place to store its local variables. Let's call this place as a scope object (some refer to it as a LexicalEnvironment). For example, when you invoke some function, and function defines local variables, these variables are saved on the scope object. You can think of it as a regular JavaScript object, with the notable difference that you can't refer to the whole object directly. You can only modify its properties, but you can't refer to the scope object itself.

This concept of scope object is very different from, say, C or C++, where local variables are stored on stack. In JavaScript, scope objects are allocated in heap instead (or at least they behave like this), so they might stay allocated even if function already returned. More on that later.

As you might expect, scope object might have parent. When the code tries to access some variable, interpreter looks for the property of current scope object. If the property doesn't exist, interpreter moves to the parent scope object, and looks there. And so on, until the value is found, or there's no more parent. Let's call this sequence of scope objects as a scope chain.

The behavior of resolving a variable on scope chain is very similar to that of prototypal inheritance, with, again, one notable difference: if you try to access some non-existing property of regular object, and prototype chain doesn't contain this property either, it's not an error: undefined is silently returned. But if you try to access non-existing property on the scope chain (i.e. access non-existing variable), then ReferenceError occurs.